# how to resolve Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: android, conflict

When I use the following two libraries simultaneously, I see an error in the build section

```
 implementation 'com.github.AbedElazizShe:LightCompressor:0.5.0'
 implementation 'com.github.AndroidDeveloperLB:VideoTrimmer:6'
```

But if I comment on any of these libraries, everything works fine
How can I fix this problem?

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.coremedia.iso.AbstractBoxParser found in modulesLightCompressor-0.5.0-runtime.jar (com.github.AbedElazizShe:LightCompressor:0.5.0) and isoparser-1.1.22.jar (com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.SilenceTrackImpl found in modules LightCompressor-0.5.0-runtime.jar (com.github.AbedElazizShe:LightCompressor:0.5.0) and isoparser-1.1.22.jar (com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22)

Duplicate class com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.TextTrackImpl$Line found in modules   LightCompressor-0.5.0-runtime.jar (com.github.AbedElazizShe:LightCompressor:0.5.0) and isoparser-1.1.22.jar (com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.h265.H265TrackImpl found in modules LightCompressor-0.5.0-runtime.jar (com.github.AbedElazizShe:LightCompressor:0.5.0) and isoparser-1.1.22.jar (com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.h265.PicTiming found in modules LightCompressor-0.5.0-runtime.jar (com.github.AbedElazizShe:LightCompressor:0.5.0) and isoparser-1.1.22.jar (com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.h265.SEIMessage found in modules LightCompressor-0.5.0-runtime.jar (com.github.AbedElazizShe:LightCompressor:0.5.0) and isoparser-1.1.22.jar (com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.h265.SequenceParameterSetRbsp found in modules LightCompressor-0.5.0-runtime.jar (com.github.AbedElazizShe:LightCompressor:0.5.0) and isoparser-1.1.22.jar (com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.h265.VideoParameterSet found in modules LightCompressor-0.5.0-runtime.jar (com.github.AbedElazizShe:LightCompressor:0.5.0) and isoparser-1.1.22.jar (com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22)
```

build.gradle(Module:app) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {


    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "abr.sport.temp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.github.AbedElazizShe:LightCompressor:0.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.AndroidDeveloperLB:VideoTrimmer:6'
}
```